# Dell laptop freezing often

Tags: 14.04, dell, gnome-shell

my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS freezes very often when doing some CPU intensive tasks. I can't control the system until the task finishes (mouse is lagging for a while, then stops responding altogether). When the task lasts too long, only option is hard reset.

I use WebStorm a lot (java app), also many node.js code compilers, espeically flow type server spawns many processes and can eat a lot of CPU.

Still i think, the system should not become unrensponsive. Maybe I am missing something? Would be glad for any help or idea.

## Screenshots of htop

Since it started I have kept running htop in second screen, since screenshotting wasnt possible - here are some photos

https://photos.app.goo.gl/GK7hYQ9SXuwW7UDe8

## Machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux pavel-xps 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Laptop: Dell XPS 9370 13"

Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 8, 
RAM 16 GB, SSD in UEFI/ESP mode

Comment: if TTY (ctrl+alt+f3) responsive (you have to give the command some time) or are TTY's entirely innacessible?

Comment: Tried before, but also lagging (the CLI cursor was blinking very slow), eventually stoped altogether. Will try again when it happens next time.

Answer (score 2):

Based on described situation and screenshots, I do suspect it is caused by problematic IO, as plenty of apps are in D-state (waiting for IO) and freezes are often related to IO issues...

1. How full is your SSD?
2. What FS are you using?
3. Have you checked health of both SSD and FS?

Also, based on your HW, have you done this firmware upgrade? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9370)#Storage

Comment: My partion is 307GB (84GB free), ext4. I will try fs+ssd checks, also the firmware could be done from my WIN dualboot. Will try - thanks for cue with the D states!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebStorm, then you might experience the same issue which I had. Most likely you test your development with chrome/chromium. After some time, the complete system freezes. I had however identified that chromium is the issue because if that one got killed, everything was fine again. You might try to kill chromium if this happens in order to troubleshoot this issue. A long term solution is to disable hardware acceleration in chromium, if you have the same issue. It solved it permanently for me.

Comment: Thank you! That seems promising. I really develop with both chrome and chromium opened at the same time. Will try without the 2nd one.